# Calculate Average Response time Calculation in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, response-time

(Attached as image[image])

"In My summary report
Total Samplers = 11944
My total Average response = 2494 mili-second = 2.49 seconds.

What i understand from here 11944 samplers are processed in average of 2.49 seconds.That means my test actually should processed for 11944 x 2.49 Seconds = 82 hours.But it actually ran about 15-20 mints max.

So trying to understand,is it reduced execution time due to JMeter parallel/multiple thread execution or i am understanding it wrong way.

I want to know a single request average response time"

Comment: How many threads you used? 40?

Comment: 50 threads  and ran for duration 6 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter calculates response time as:

- Sum of all [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) response times
- Divided by the number of samplers

basically it's [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of all samplers response times.

11944 x 2.49 / 3600 gives **8.2 hours** and yes, this is how much time it would take to execute the test with a **single user**, the amount of time will reduce proportionally depending on the number of threads used

More information:

- [Calculator class source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java)
- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Understanding Your Reports: Part 2 - KPI Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-2-kpi-correlations?utm_source=Blog&utm_medium=BM_Blog&utm_campaign=kpis-part1)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on threads number you used

For example if you used 50 threads 12K Samples/requests and each time took (average of) 2.5 seconds

```
12000  *  2.5    /     50    /    60           = 10 minutes
^          ^           ^          ^
requests  avg. sec     threads   sec per minute
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification